# Maximum calls does not exceed on certain code inside function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, recursion, callstack

My question is rather simple. I just don't understand this behavior that is happening in my NodeJS environment.

The code below does not exceed maximum function call stack:

```
const loop = (i, maxI) => {
    if (i === maxI) {
        return;
    }

    if (i % 1000 === 0) {
        console.log(i);
    } 

    return loop(i + 1, maxI)
}

if (!module.parent) {
    loop(0, 100000000000000000);
}
```

However the code below somehow does blow the stack up?

```
const loop = (i, maxI) => {
    if (i === maxI) {
        return;
    }

    if (i % 10000 === 0) {
        console.log(i);
    } 

    return loop(i + 1, maxI)
}

if (!module.parent) {
    loop(0, 100000000000000000);
}
```

Even this blows the stack up:

```
const loop = (i, maxI) => {
    if (i === maxI) {
        return;
    }

    return loop(i + 1, maxI)
}

if (!module.parent) {
    loop(0, 100000000000000000);
}
```

I am using NodeJS v10.15.1 on Windows 10. I am guessing tail recursion is not optimized in NodeJS but how does that one particular scenario not cause the function call stack to blow up?

Comment: I wonder if `console.log` provides enough delay for things to get cleaned up??

Comment: Weird. If I do anything after `loop(0, ...)`, like just `1;` on the console, then the first snippet also throws `too much recursion`; but not if I just let it run 

Comment: It blows in Node.js 6 and 8, but does not blow in Node.js 10 and 11. But It seems that it does not blow just because it exits prematurely without error. Seems like a bug?

Comment: The issue in the Node.js repository: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/25930

Answer (score 0):

This happens because JS has a stack in which it queues the calls to the functions and there is a limit of the memory assigned to that stack.

You should wrap your recursive function call into a setTimeout, setImmediate or process.nextTick function to give node.js the chance to clear the stack. If you don't do that and there are many loops without any real async function call or if you do not wait for the callback, your RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded will be inevitable.

That said, Now In your first code you are doing

```
i % 1000
```

which a comparatively lighter operation than the operation done in your second code

```
i % 10000
```

The 1st piece of code gets run too many times because the stack is getting freed up by the time next call is queued but in the second piece of code, The processor is still doing the operation while the calls get stacked up. The third piece of code actually runs for a lot many times but eventually returns the error because again the stack was clogged.

Please try and put a log statement in the third piece of code and try it. That will make things clearer for you.